# Interpret output from coxph with frailty in Rs finalfit

Tags: r, cox-model

Edit: If anyone is interested, I can upload a csv.

I'm using a coxph model in R to analyse data that look like this:

```
       id  year    start stop event education household_position occupation urban
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <fct>      <fct>              <fct>      <fct>
 1 1860001  1965     0     1     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 2 1860001  1966     1     2     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 3 1860001  1967     2     3     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 4 1860001  1968     3     4     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 5 1860001  1969     4     5     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 6 1860001  1970     5     6     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 7 1860001  1971     6     7     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 8 1860001  1972     7     8     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
 9 1860001  1973     8     9     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes  
10 1860001  1974     9    10     0 elementary parent             unskilled  yes
.
.
.
521 1900195  2020    15    16     0 elementary parent             unskilled    yes  
522 1900196  2005     0     1     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
523 1900196  2006     1     2     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
524 1900196  2007     2     3     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
525 1900196  2008     3     4     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
526 1900196  2009     4     5     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
527 1900196  2010     5     6     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
528 1900196  2011     6     7     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
529 1900196  2012     7     8     0 elementary parent             white_collar no   
530 1900196  2013     8     9     0 elementary parent             white_collar no
```

It's about 13,000 rows in total with some time-variant covariates (occupation and urban). Using the finalfit() package, I wrote the following code:

```
explanatory <- c("education", "occupation", "urban", "household_position", "frailty(id)")
dependent <- c("Surv(start, stop, event)")

dat %>%
  finalfit(dependent, explanatory)
```

The output is:

```
 Dependent: Surv(start, stop, event)                             all          HR (univariable)        HR (multivariable)
                           education        elementary 11477 (100.0)                         -                         -
                                                higher  1250 (100.0) 2.25 (1.69-3.00, p<0.001) 2.70 (1.54-4.75, p=0.001)
                                     unknown_or_little   337 (100.0) 1.28 (0.66-2.49, p=0.464)                         -
                          occupation         unskilled  4665 (100.0)                         -                         -
                                               skilled  1454 (100.0) 1.43 (1.03-1.98, p=0.033) 1.17 (0.75-1.81, p=0.492)
                                               farmers   932 (100.0) 0.10 (0.02-0.39, p=0.001) 0.12 (0.03-0.51, p=0.004)
                                          white_collar   899 (100.0) 1.13 (0.73-1.75, p=0.585) 0.64 (0.34-1.23, p=0.179)
                                                 elite   267 (100.0) 2.61 (1.55-4.39, p<0.001) 0.76 (0.33-1.76, p=0.516)
                                         no_occupation  4847 (100.0) 0.71 (0.54-0.93, p=0.012) 0.77 (0.55-1.10, p=0.150)
                               urban                no 10509 (100.0)                         -                         -
                                                   yes  2555 (100.0) 1.43 (1.11-1.85, p=0.005) 1.21 (0.87-1.68, p=0.264)
                  household_position            parent  8422 (100.0)                         -                         -
                                                 child  3279 (100.0) 0.68 (0.52-0.91, p=0.009) 0.93 (0.65-1.33, p=0.694)
                                              relative   300 (100.0) 0.39 (0.13-1.23, p=0.108)                         -
                                                lodger  1063 (100.0) 1.56 (1.14-2.15, p=0.006) 1.51 (1.02-2.24, p=0.040)
                         frailty(id)                                                         -                         -
                                <NA>              <NA>          <NA>                      <NA> 1.26 (0.49-3.26, p=0.631)
                                <NA>              <NA>          <NA>                      <NA> 0.61 (0.17-2.14, p=0.442)
```

I'm unsure why not all HRs are shown in the columns HR (multivariable). HRs for *relative* and *unknown_or_little* I believe are shown next to frailty(id). When removing the frailty term, the HRs are presented the same way as all other factors. Is there a reason for why the HRs are not shown next to the factor names?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about output formatting rather than statistics.

Comment: @EdM I construe it as a question about dummy variable coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The issue seems to be that it's not possible to have factor names longer than 10 characters. When I renamed the factors it worked fine. Also, I renamed the `household_position` covariate to `hh.position`.